# Regular Expression to get value between substrings

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get values from the current string:

```
String s = "%5B%22VALUE1%22%2C+%22VALUE2.com%22%5D";
```

I was using:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("%.*?22");
```

which gives the following:

```
VALUE1
VALUE2.com
5D
```

Since I am rather new using regex I would love to have some help. May someone tell me how to get rid of the `5D` as well?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you want all the values between `%22` ?

Comment: there could be also values behind the 5D, but I've already solved it on my own (sorry for bothering)

Comment: If one of the answers solves your problem then please accept it, or close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("%.*?(?:22|$)");
```

Comment: thank you, I've solved it the ugly way ("%.*?22|%5\w") which is providing me the same substrings as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Use lookahead to make sure `22` is followed:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("%(?=.*?22).*?22");
```